# How to install rqlite on a java project

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I want to use `rqlite` for my sqlite database replication on a java desktop application. i have found a [java coding example in here](https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite-java). But I have no idea how to add rqlite binary/library files to the project.

I'm using `Netbeans` `Ant` for create the project. I used add `jar` library files to the project. But I can't find any `jar` files for `rqlite`

If anyone here have any experience or knowledge, please let me know how to do it

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this. You may already have done part 1, but I mention it for clarity.

---

**(1) The rqlite database**

You install rqlite (the relational database) separately from your Java project - just like you would install other relational database products separately. You can get pre-built binaries [here](https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite/releases) (see the "Assets" section) or you can build from source.

Note that the pre-built binaries are only for Linux and Mac. Otherwise, see the notes for Windows in the above link, for more details.

rqlite is also available via [Docker build](https://hub.docker.com/r/rqlite/rqlite/).

---

**(2) Accessing your rqlite database via Java**

Here are two approaches:

(a) You can use rqlite's [data API](https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite/blob/master/DOC/DATA_API.md) using any suitable HTTP client. Java has a [built-in HTTP client](https://openjdk.org/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html) from Java 11 onwards.

There is also a [Google HTTP client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client) - and probably various other similar libraries.

So, with the above approach, there is no "rqlite client" JAR file.

(b) Use the [rqlite-java](https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite-java) library you linked to in your question (I have never tried it). I see that this library uses Google's HTTP client, internally. In other words, it looks like it is a wrapper around the rqlite data API, mentioned above.

There does not appear to be a pre-built JAR for this library (at least not that I was able to find) so you will need to build that yourself from the GitHub repository. You can fork (copy) the repo into a new, separate Java project to build it on your machine, using Maven (or you can download all the source code as a zip file).

If you are not familiar with these GitHub & Maven build processes, there are guides and tutorials to get you started.

You tagged your question as a NetBeans question - so you would create a "Java with Maven" project for this.

[image]